# how can I put in HTML certain information form my json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having problem with my data.
My JSon looks like that:

```
[
    {
        "link": {
            "created_at": "2013-10-07T13:31:43+09:00",
            "id": 8,
            "items_count": 4,
            "key": "0iqVSnTU-BtJ1ItVKRe2VMWvRMU",
            "mode": "standard",
            "name": "sdasadads",
            "pusher_key": "1jtsrzl3n6i1DKA3tSZJM6LPnfQ",
            "readonly_key": "R_dD5oHMsruu0YzYVKEOA8hKKXA-r",
            "updated_at": "2013-10-08T14:06:07+09:00",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "link": {
            "created_at": "2013-10-07T13:32:56+09:00",
            "id": 9,
            "items_count": 1,
            "key": "Mj-6Cc-_qaGlVTPgqKexzeijYNA",
            "mode": "standard",
            "name": "Untitled2",
            "pusher_key": "hGE0D8TSar_H_Gv9MWdpj26gamM",
            "readonly_key": "T53SNKPgyf7KvRUMzDQPaM99AAc-r",
            "updated_at": "2013-10-07T13:33:14+09:00",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "link": {
            "created_at": "2013-10-11T11:18:06+09:00",
            "id": 10,
            "items_count": 0,
            "key": "X_ZoKxFPHtsvSU5W11gXx1653FU",
            "mode": "standard",
            "name": "Usdadasas",
            "pusher_key": "0PZ860awofRKB9XIrXba-xY6u14",
            "readonly_key": "2rzrRZAaR7UZRK3UbUId8xmFzd4-r",
            "updated_at": "2013-10-11T11:18:06+09:00",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to print put all the names of the links like that:

```
$.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data[link][0].name;
      });
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I grub all the names and put it in html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The objects are inside the array, not the other way around.
- `link` is a literal property name, not a variable containing one as a string

Thus:

```
data[0]['link']['name']
```

You'll also need to make sure that the response has an `application/json` content type.

Grabbing all the names will require you to use a loop and change the `0` each time round it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all change last "}" to "]" (your top structure is array not object )

Then try this

```
$.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data[0].link.name;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good way to fetch something from data structure. With your test data in data variable, could would look like this:

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/shKRX/)

```
<div class="names"></div>
```

```
var names = data.map(function (item) {
    return item.link.name
});

document.querySelector(".names").innerHTML = names;
```